styling a "custom elements"
I am playing around with creating my own framework where I inject content into 'custom elements' (I am not sure how to refer to them correctly .. they are not custom elements as they are not web components)
Is there a way to correctly put styles on html elements that are not part of the standard ? I can't see why ie border or float can't work ? the debugger seems to show that the browser correctly calculates their size.
For example the following give a strange result :(


<style>
  .border { border:solid }
</style>

<custom-  class="border">
  <div>
    hello
  </div>
</custom->




You get a better result if you change the div to span.

The default display property for your element is inline, so it's not calculating the width properly based on the contained div.
Changing it to inline-block or block makes it work as desired.


<style>
  .border { border:solid }
  custom- { display: inline-block; }
</style>

<custom-  class="border">
  <div>
    hello
  </div>
</custom->




You can can create your own custom elements in HTML, but they are display: inline by default, so (depending on the result you want) you may have to specify a particular display (e.g. display: block) to get the result you want.


.border {
  border: solid;
  display: block;
}
<custom- class="border">
  <div>
    hello
  </div>
</custom->



